# mostrar dato dinámico select - php

Tags: javascript, php

buen día, tengo dos selects dinámicos donde el segundo select muestra información dependiendo lo que el primer select seleccione hasta ahi todo funciona bien, **pero necesito pasarle un segundo parámetro de consulta al segundo select don quiero remplazar `"talla_dtl = M"` por el resultado del primer select pero no he logrado sacar el valor y enviarlo a la consulta del segundo select.**

**lo único que he podido lograr es traer de forma dinámica el resultado al seleccionar el primer select pero no he podido implementar el resto.**

index.php

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','hostcrea_pruebas2','Kenryug=00','hostcrea_pruebas2');
  
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Llenar select a partir de otro con php y mysql</title>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <h2>Llenar un select a partir de otro select con jquery y php</h2>

            <label>SELECT 1 (Tallas)</label>
            
        <select  id="lista1" name="lista1">
        <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
        <?php
          $query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT distinct (talla_dtl), idPro_dtl FROM dtl_product WHERE idPro_dtl = 86");
          while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$valores[idPro_dtl].'">'.$valores[talla_dtl].'</option>';
             
          }
     
        ?>
      </select>

<!-- Traer la talla seleccionada -->      
<script>     
        var select = document.getElementById('lista1');
select.addEventListener('change',
  function(){
    var selectedOption = this.options[select.selectedIndex];
    console.log("AQUI PUEDO VER EL VALOR DINAMICO DEL PRIMER SELECT PARA EL SEGUNDO SELECT QUE NECESITO PARA LA CONSULTA" + ': ' + selectedOption.text);
  });
 
 </script> 
      
            <br>
            <div id="select2lista"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#lista1').val(0);
        recargarLista();
    

        $('#lista1').change(function(){
            recargarLista();
        
        });
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function recargarLista(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"datos.php",
            data:"continente=" + $('#lista1').val(),
            success:function(r){
                $('#select2lista').html(r);
                
            }
            
        });
    }
    
    
</script>
```

datos.php

```php
<?php 
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','hostcrea_pruebas2','Kenryug=00','hostcrea_pruebas2');
$continente=$_POST['continente'];

    
    $sql="  SELECT id_dtlPro,
             idPro_dtl,
             color_dtl,
             talla_dtl
        from dtl_product 
        where idPro_dtl='$continente' and talla_dtl= 'M' " ;
        
    //DONDE DICE talla_dtl= 'M' QUIERO TRAER EL VALOR DEL TEXTO SELECCCIONADO DEL PRIMER SELECT.
  

    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    $cadena="<label>SELECT 2 (color)</label> 
            <select id='lista2' name='lista2'>";

    while ($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $cadena=$cadena.'<option value='.$ver[0].'>'.utf8_encode($ver[2]).'</option>';
    }

    echo  $cadena."</select>";
    

?>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy confusa y la lógica que estás siguiendo para todo esto también. Por favor siéntate con tranquilidad y explica verbalmente y con claridad qué es lo que quieres lograr, explica también el contexto. Ambas cosas ahora son más importantes que el código que has escrito, pues me parece que la lógica que sigues en él no es idónea para resolver este tipo de problemas.